# Approximation of series

Tags: approximation, approximation-theory

Can anyone provide an approximation for the series:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1-\Gamma\left(i+1,\frac{b^{2}}{N_{01}}\right)\right)v^{-i-1}}{\mu_{1}N_{01}^{i}}\\\times \sum_{j=0}^{i}e^{-av}\frac{\left(av\right)^{j}}{j!}\left(1-\frac{2}{\left(i-j\right)!}\left(\frac{cv}{\mu_{2}\alpha_{1}^{2}}\right)^{\frac{1+i-j}{2}}K_{j-i-1}\left(2\sqrt{\frac{cv}{\mu_{2}\alpha_{1}^{2}}}\right)\right)?$$

Where $K_i$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind and all parameters are positive real numbers.